# Splitting large text files with Perl

Tags: perl

I have to split a large, 1.8Tb text file in two (I need only the second half of the file). The file has `\n` as the record separator.

I tried

```
perl -ne 'print if $. >= $line_to_start_from' test.txt > result.txt
```

on a much smaller, 115Mb test file and it did the job but took 22 seconds.

Using this solution for a 1.8Tb file will take unreasonably long time, so my question is whether there is a way in Perl to split huge files without looping over them?

Comment: What about using `tail`?

Comment: what is your criterion to find the split point? If it's just to roughly split in half, seek() to (-s $file) / 2, skip to the next \n, then read() in large chunks (like 1Mb) and copy to output. It's still going to take a while though.

Comment: There is a number of Unix tools designed to do this kind of job but I would like to know if this task is possible with Perl. As the language offers more flexibility.

Comment: If there is a need to identify a place in a file, even if that means merely the number of lines, then the file must be read. No magic tricks.  Can't find line no. X unless all previous linefeeds are seen and counted

Comment: @zdim, the Unix utility 'split' split my 115Mb test file on a desired line onwards in a fraction of second. The question is how does it do it and why it cannot be done in Perl.

Comment: `split` is typically a compiled C program intended to do one thing, and likely uses low-level (Possibly OS specific) syscalls. Many fewer layers involved than a perl script. Of course it's going to run faster.

Comment: Interesting question buried in here. The behavior of perl varies wildly depending on how long the average line is in that file. If the lines are thousands of characters long, perl is just about as fast as split. If the lines only have a couple of characters each, perl is orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: You can also try `sed -n 'line_to_start_from,$p' test.txt > result.txt` which might be a bit faster than the perl equivalent. But the best perl way is probably the way Dave described.

Comment: Can you answer the original question: how do you decide where to split the file?  By a line number? Or file size (as in, split-in-half for example)? Or some pattern?

Comment: By the line number. I hinted on it by putting $line_to_start_from in the one-liner.

Comment: "_By the line number_" -- thank you (yeah i noticed that just wanted to confirm).  So for how long does this run on your 115 Mb file: `perl -we'$f=shift//die"need filename\n"; open $fh, $f; while (<$fh>) { last if $.>=10 }; print <$fh>' text.txt > result.txt`  (replace "10" with your needed line number) ?  The quoted 22 seconds is much too long. It took the above one-liner 1.15 seconds on a 123Mb file with 4million lines, to extract everything after line 2 million (so about a half -- output is 62Mb). That's on a 7-8 year old laptop with perl 5.16

Comment: In summary, to get the second half of a 123Mb large file `split` takes 0.62 seconds and perl's one-liner in my previous comment 1.15 seconds, on my mentioned laptop.  That ain't bad for perl at all I say.

Comment: It'll take some 2 hours or so to copy a Tb of data.  (If you needed the second half you could truncate once you find the spot -- and lose the original file -- but I don't know whether it's possible to change the beginning of a file by moving some pointer so to avoid the data copy...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default perl reads file input one line at a time. If your file contains lots of relatively short lines (and I'm assuming it does), perl will be a lot slower than utilities like `split` which read in bigger chunks from the file at a time.

For testing, I created a ~200MB file with very short lines:

```
$ perl -e 'print "123\n" for( 1 .. 50_000_000 );' >file_to_split
```

`split` can handle it pretty reasonably:

```
$ time split --lines=25000000 file_to_split half

real    0m1.266s
user    0m0.314s
sys     0m0.213s
```

And the naïve perl approach is much slower:

```
$ time perl -ne 'print if $. > 25_000_000' file_to_split >second_half

real    0m10.474s
user    0m10.257s
sys     0m0.222s
```

But you can use the `$/` special variable to cause perl to read more than one line at a time. For example 16 kb of data at a time:

```
my $CHUNK_SIZE = 16 * 1024;
my $SPLIT_AT_LINE = 25_000_000;

{
    local $/ = \$CHUNK_SIZE;
    my $lineNumber = 0;
    while ( <> ) {
        if ( $lineNumber > $SPLIT_AT_LINE ) {
            # everything from here on is in the second half
            print $_;
        }
        else {
            my $count = $_ =~ tr/\n/\n/;
            $lineNumber += $count;
            if ( $lineNumber > $SPLIT_AT_LINE ) {
                # we went past the split, get some of the lines from this buffer
                my $extra = $lineNumber - $SPLIT_AT_LINE;
                my @lines = split m/\n/, $_, $count - $extra + 1;
                print $lines[ -1 ];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't care about overshooting the split by a few lines, you could make this code even simpler. And this gets perl to do the same operation in a reasonable amount of time:

```
$ time perl test.pl file_to_split >second_half

real    0m0.678s
user    0m0.095s
sys     0m0.297s
```